# Compute the first five non-zero terms of the Taylor series about $a=4$ for $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

This is my first Taylor Series problem and I want to make sure I completed it correctly.  Here is the question:

Compute the first five non-zero terms of the Taylor series about $a=4$ for $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$

I made a table of derivatives and plugged in $a=4$:

$$f(x)=x^{\frac{1}{2}}=2$$
$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^{-\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{1}{4}$$
$$f''(x)=-\frac{1}{4}x^{-\frac{3}{2}}=-\frac{1}{32}$$
$$f'''(x)=\frac{3}{8}x^{-\frac{5}{2}}=\frac{3}{256}$$
$$f^{(4)}(x)=-\frac{15}{16}x^{-\frac{7}{2}}=-\frac{15}{2048}$$

So I then wrote out the terms this way:

$$\sqrt{x}=2+\frac{1}{4*1!}\left(x-4\right)-\frac{1}{32*2!}\left(x-4\right)^2+\frac{3}{256*3!}\left(x-4\right)^3-\frac{15}{2048*4!}\left(x-4\right)^4$$

Is this correct or close?  If not, any hints to get me going?

Comment: Assuming you've got the rest of the values correct, you're set!

Comment: @Fantini That's so encouraging!  I'm trying to build up confidence for my final exam in a few days.  Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure how you write your questions in your exams, but be careful to avoid writing like you did here. It was clear what you were doing, but in a formal exam do not write $$f' '(x) = - \frac{1}{4} x^{-3/2} = - \frac{1}{32}.$$ Either subtitute $x=a$ in everything or exclude the second equality and just mention "using $a=4$ we obtain..."

Comment: @Fantini On paper I actually wrote out a table of just the derivatives and then a separate tables plugging in my $a$.  I wrote it this way in my question because I wasn't sure of how else to make it clear for you guys.  Thanks for that suggestion!

Comment: This ia perfectly done ! Congratulations.